# Basic Django Chat Using Sockets Not Sending To The Browser

Tags: javascript, python, django, sockets

If anybody can help with this conundrum.

This is the django socket server for an absolutly un authenticated chat, everything is working upto saving the entry to the database. But the send event is not reaching the browser.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from pages.models import Message


clients = []


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Start Web Sockets"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        global clients

        @sync_to_async
        def update(data):

            print('** Saving **')
            message = Message(message=data)
            message.save()

        async def handler(websocket):
            while True:
                data = await websocket.recv()

                print('** Received **')
                clients.append({'websocket': websocket})
                await update(data)

                print('** Broadcasting **')
                for client in clients:
                    this_websocket = client['websocket']
                    await this_websocket.send(data)

                print('** Sent **')

        async def main():
            async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8765):
                await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

        asyncio.run(main())
```

In the browser I have the following code submit works as it triggers the socket server to respond and save the data to the database, yet it dosn't send anything to the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Open Web Socket

    websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765/");

    // Display Submitted Messages

    websocket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('** Recieved Message **');
        var html = '<div class="s-chat__message">'
        html += event.data;
        html += '</div>';
    });

    // Submit A Message

    $('#message').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        websocket.send($('#id_message').val());
        $('#message-input').val('');
    });

});
```

Comment: Seems to work in the browser, but not from python.

`websocket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
});
undefined
websocket.send('text');
undefined
Message from server  text
`

I think its the broadcast section in the python thats failing.